# Quest Toad Default Schema Upon Logon

Tags: oracle, toad, quest

Our Oracle database has 500+ database users ( one for each 'human' user ). We are using TOAD Version 11.5

After every logon, I have to switch to the application schema, which means choosing the schema from a very long "users" dropdown list.

Is there a way to set a default schema upon logon ?

Comment: When establishing connection, why don't you enter the application schema's credentials? That's the *default* schema, isn't it?

Comment: We are not given password to application schema. We can only Browse it.

Comment: When you connect to this database, will you always be connecting as the application schema? If so, you can create a trigger that will run `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=[SCHEMA]` where [SCHEMA] is the name of the application schema. Otherwise, this seems like kind of an odd request. If you are not allowed to know the application schema password, I would caution to think that someone within your organization doesn't want you signing into that schema - perhaps for auditing reasons, or for some other reason. Just because you can browse a schema does not mean you should log in as it.

Comment: After a few reads and your latest comment... "We can only Browse it" I answered based on what I think is your problem. If you are trying to login as schema A, but have all of your actions performed as schema B then you need another game plan like the `ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = XYZ` route or possibly Proxy Authentication. Search Oracle docs, AskTom, etc. for Proxy Authentication. It allows you to login with schema A connecting through schema B without actually knowing schema B's password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to pre-select the schema in the Schema Browser, for example, then right-click the Schema Dropdown and choose the "Set XYZ as Default Schema" menu item. If you are referring to some other place in Toad then please be specific.

[image: Set Default Schema]

Comment: Thanks Michael S. That was the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Or set the schema in `Customize` as a "Favorite".

Answer (score 0):

You can set an Auto Connect connection too.  From the session/new connection window, scroll right and check the box for "Auto Connect" on the connection you want. When you start Toad, it will auto-connect to the entry you selected.